# How to create an api for excel upload with laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

**strong text**
I want to create a simple api that will allow me upload an excel file and insert it to my database using laravel 5.7 and vue. When I tried to call it via postman or vue it keeps throwing error 500 internal server error on submit. Here is my controller function below:

```
    //Upload Students
    public function postUploadSudents( Request $request ) {


        if ( $request->hasFile( 'file' ) ) {
            $fileName = Carbon::now()->timestamp . $request->file( 'file' )->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file( 'file' )->move( 'uploads/students', $fileName );
            $fileUrl = url( 'uploads/students/' . $fileName );
        } else {
            session()->flash( 'error', 'Please attach a file.' );

            return redirect()->back();
        }


        try {


            $downloadUrl = url( "/uploads/students/" . $fileName );

            /* Identify file, create reader and load file  */
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( getcwd() . "/" . "uploads/students/" . $fileName );
            $objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( $inputFileType );
            $objPHPExcel   = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( getcwd() . "/" . "uploads/students/" . $fileName );

            $sheet         = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $highestRow    = $sheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
            $time_pre      = microtime( true );

            //  Read a row of data into an array
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray( 'A2:' . $highestColumn . $highestRow,
                null, false, false );

            $count = 0;

            $failedImports = array();

            DB::beginTransaction();
            // add students to database from file
            foreach ( $rowData as $cell ) {
                $count ++;
                try {


                    $date        = "";
                    $dateCell    = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell( 'G' . ( $count + 1 ) );
                    $invalidDate = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell( 'G' . ( $count + 1 ) )->getValue();
                    if ( PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime( $dateCell ) ) {
                        $date = date( "d-m-Y", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP( $invalidDate ) );
                    }


                    $student                            = new StudentRecord();
                    $student->first_name                = $cell[0];
                    $student->last_name                 = $cell[1];
                    $student->matric_number             = $cell[2];
                    $student->registration_number       = $cell[4];
                    $student->level                     = $cell[5];
                    $student->department                = $cell[6];
                    $student->date_of_birth             = $date;
                    $student->nationality               = $cell[8];
                    $student->state_of_origin           = $cell[9];
                    $student->lga                       = $cell[10];
                    $student->email                     = strtolower($cell[11]);
                    // $student->password                   = bcrypt( "fuaa123" );
                    $student->dashboard_number          = $cell[12];
                    $student->phone_number              = $cell[13];
                    $student->home_address              = $cell[14];
                    $student->ip_address                = $cell[15];


                    $student->save();


                } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
                    return $e->getMessage();
                    array_push( $failedImports, $count );
                }

            }

            DB::commit();
            if ( count( $failedImports ) > 0 ) {
                $error = "";
                foreach ( $failedImports as $item ) {
                    $error .= ",$item";
                }

                $failed = count( $failedImports );
                // session()->flash( 'error', "$failed did not import. [$error] " );

                // an alternative to session flash above
                return response(array("message" => "Failed did not import", "data" => $failed), 406);


            }

            //$number = $count - count( $failedImports );
            //$request->session()->flash( "success", "$count records in total. $number uploaded." );

            // return redirect()->back();


            return response(array("message"=>"Successful", "data" => $student), 200);

        } catch ( \Exception $exception ){

            return response (array(["message"=>"Something went wrong. Please try again", $exception]),400);

            // session()->flash('error','Something went wrong. Please try again.');
            // return redirect()->back();
        }

    }
```

and my api.php route link:

```
//StudentRecords Upload Routes
Route::post('/uploadStudents','StudentRecordController@postUploadSudents');
```

Comment: What do the logs say caused that 500 error?

Comment: you might need to disable csrf checking for that route

Comment: oh ok let me try that and see thanks @Peter

Comment: @commanderZiltoid ok the log keeps saying `Class App\Http\Controllers\API\StudentRecordController does not exist`
That's the error in the log.
Note that class does exist
I wonder why it cant see it. I've I kept trying but still